# Can i make a class that behave like a primitive type?

Tags: java, oop

I made a Point class to manage xy coordinate (I know some java default packages already have some Point object that behave in a similar way, I use it as a lazy alternative and this is an example, please dont mind it ^^).

Before using it I was using the int primitive type.

thing is, when passing a class or a primitive type as parameter of a method, both don't act the same way, if I change the value of a primitive variable in a method, the original variable is unaffected, unlike if I was using an object since its the reference that is passed as parameter.

my problem is that since I use Point for math (example below), I have to manually create new object to save the result and I never use it to have a "link" between two variables as I could with how object behave usually.

My Point class:

```
public class Point {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point(int nx, int ny) {
        this.x = nx;
        this.y = ny;
    }

    public Point() {
        this(0, 0);
    }
}
```

An example of method:

```
public Point getAdjacent(int x, int y, Direction dir) {
        Point pt = new Point(x, y);//basically, i would like to do that automatically
        switch (dir) {
        case Up:
            pt.y -= 1;
            break;
        case Down:
            pt.y += 1;
            break;
        case Right:
            pt.x -= 1;
            break;
        case Left:
            pt.x += 1;
            break;
        default:
            //do nothing
        }
        return pt;
    }
```

To summarize, **is it possible to make Point behave like a primitive type?**

EDIT: i mean that it would automatically copy it when passing it as parameter or doing point1=point2

Comment: There is no way to do this in Java without making the object immutable and any operation on that will return a new instance of the object.

Comment: When a non-primitive type is passed through into a method argument, or otherwise copied, it is shallow copied, meaning that you copy a pointer to the actual object, as if you have two names for the same object. What you are looking for is to deep copy the object, create a .clone() method in your Point class. It should just return a new point with the same x and y coordinates as the original.

Comment: So basically, you want to pass a Point object and return the adjacent point from it right?
You should make Point implement Cloneable and implement/use the method .clone() for this purpose.

Comment: or have a copy constructor.

Comment: Since the result of determining the adjacency is a `Point` then you basically *have* to create a new instance because your method handles both the X and Y axes (or split it into 2 methods that deal with each case separately which seems backwards). Is there a reason you want to avoid creating a new instance?

Comment: I strongly agree with @AbhijithNagarajan , making your object immutable is one of the best ways to avoid accidentally modifying the fields of another instance with a reference to the same object. I would avoid the copy constructor alone because it's very easy to forget to use a clone of your instance. Rather, you can have methods such as `public Point addX(int)`. I find it best to write a class interface based on how that class is intended to be used.

Comment: As an aside I would make your `Point` class immutable and create it *after* you have worked out the adjacent XY values, i.e. make the fields and the class itself `final` so they cannot be fiddled outside of the class. (They are fine as `public` for a 'value' class like this).  EDIT: As other previous posters have suggested.

Comment: @DSOI__UNUNOCTIUM are you sure about that? isn't it references("pointer") that are passed as parameters? deep or shallow copy doesn't change a lot there, since my Point object only handle primitive type

Comment: @TheTeluri yes, they are, since you are passing in a reference to the same object (shallow copying), you are going to change that object, but if you use `.clone()` it will make an identical copy, changing one will not effect the other (deep copying). Your ints are not being copied at all. When you have a variable that is not a primitive type, it is only a reference to the object, no matter if it only has primitive types in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question might be a bit too broad, because one could argue quite extensively about what the word "behave" should mean. But to some extent, we can sort this out:

The shortest answer might be: **No, this is not possible.**

A slightly more elaborate answer might be: **No, it is not *yet* possible to let a class (or more precisely: an object) behave like a primitive value.**

---

The long answer:

There are efforts to achieve a behavior that might come close to what you're trying to accomplish. The relevant keyword here is **Value Types**.

Some resources:

- The original value types proposal by John Rose, Brian Goetz, and Guy Steele: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/values/values-0.html
- The relevant JEP for Value Objects: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/169
- The Wiki describing the goals and current state of value types: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/valhalla/L-World+Value+Types
- The relevant mailing list: https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/valhalla-dev/

However, this is not supported in current versions of Java and the JVM, and it might still take a while until the details are sorted out.

Until then, there are some conceivable workarounds to achieve the desired goal.

The simplest solution is the one that you already proposed: You always return a new instance instead of modifying a given object.

<sub>The example that you showed in the question might not be the best to illustrate this, because the method `getAdjacent` that you showed could in fact be a `static` method. It does not use the instance that it is called on in any way.</sub>

Then you could always be sure that you received a new instance for each modification. Otherwise, imagine this code snippet:

```
Point a = new Point(1,2);
Point b = new Point(3,4);

a.add(b);

System.out.println(a); // What does this print?
```

Depending on the implementation of the `add` method, the behavior might not be clear. If it was implemented like this:

```
public void add(Point other) {
    this.x += other.x;
    this.y += other.y;
}
```

then the point `a` would be modified, and the output would be `(4,6)`.

But if it was implemented like this

```
public Point add(Point other) {
    return new Point(this.x+other.x, this.y+other.y);
}
```

then `a` would remain unaffected, and the output would still be `(1,2)`.

In general, making something like a `Point` **immutable** basically enforces this style of programming. So you could make the variables `x` and `y` in your class `final`, so that you could always be sure that the object cannot be modified after it was created:

```
public class Point {

    // Note that these are FINAL:   
    private final int x; 
    private final int y;

    public Point(int nx, int ny) {
        this.x = nx;
        this.y = ny;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

There are some further design considerations for such a seemingly trivial thing like a `Point` class (some of which I mentioned in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68109/vector-physics-implementation/68119#68119)), but discussing them is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed that method was static (i thought it was a good idea to remove it to keep it clear, my mistake) and thats nice to know im not trying to do something meaningless :D

Answer (score 1):

**First of all:** be sure to use break statements in your switch code. Otherwise when case Up is matched, the switch block will "fall through" and will execute:

```
pt.y -= 1; 
pt.y += 1;
pt.x -= 1;
pt.x += 1;
```

(Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

---

According to the question, you can indeed use the Point class. Below code will:
 1. Use a Point as input.
 2. Extract the variables x and y from the input Point into a copy primitive.
 3. Change the copied primitives.
 4. Create a new Point, based on the copies.

In this way the "old" Point will be left untouched.

```
public Point getAdjacent(final Point point, final Direction dir) {
    int x = point.x;
    int y = point.y;
    switch (dir) {
        case Up:
            y -= 1;
            break;
        case Down:
            y += 1;
            break;
        case Right:
            x -= 1;
            break;
        case Left:
            x += 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction on switch, i tweaked it to not distract of the main question. I dont know about your solution, making two new x and y var ultimately add lines where i was trying to remove them :D.